# Should Tag-Links on users page include userid and timeframe

Tags: discussion, tags, users-page

On the [UsersPage](https://stackoverflow.com/users), each User lists the specific tags he/she gained reputation for in the selected time frame (week, month, quarter, year, all)

[image]

The Tag-Links currently link to all tagged question (example: [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)

Should the links not include the `userid` and `timeframe` (maybe using the new search engine of stackoverflow), so that the resulting page only contains the answers and questions of the corresponding tag the user gained repution.

Using the links for the first time i really expected to get a filtered result instead of a full list with all tagged questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I agree that `userid` should be in the filter, I don't think `timeframe` would be a suitable addition.

The question tag list itself is **already** ordered by date asked, so in order to gauge what questions had been answered in that timeframe you could navigate through that list yourself in order to get a general idea of what was answered.

However, the date asked doesn't always correlate with the date answered (answering old posts, etc.), but it does catch the majority of the cases.

Comment: you are right. I think it would be enough to include the userid. The reputation can be gained by older post, so that the timeframe would not help here to list this posts